# Errors when iostringstream::write is called

Tags: c++, iostream, std

On [this website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/), the description of the `iostringstream::write` function says that:

> In case of error, the badbit flag is set

What could those errors be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious error when writing to a stringstream would be if the underlying stringbuffer failed to allocate memory to hold the data being written. Also note, however, that the link you've given is to `ostream::write`, which could fail for other reasons (e.g., writing to a pipe that's been closed or a file on a disk that's full and/or the write would exceed what the user's allowed).

Aside #1: there's no such thing as an `iostringstream` -- there's `istringstream` and `ostringstream`. The one that combines both is just `stringstream`.

Aside #2: cplusplus.com isn't particularly highly respected. Some other sites (e.g., cppreference.com) seem to be more dependable/accurate, at least as a general rule (though I feel obliged to point out that I don't use any of the above much myself, so my comments on them aren't anywhere close to the last word).